# How to filter layer features by value?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use Mapbox GL JS for visualization massive dataset. And now I try to create several checkboxes for filtering some features of a tileset by its value. Dataset was uploaded to Mapbox through Mapbox Studio.

For example, there is field SortOfFruit. I would make checkboxes for Orange, Apples, Mangoes, etc. When checkbox Orange checked then oranges appear on map. How to do it?

I tried to use [Mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/), there was solved similar task, but I can't adapting it to my purpose. There use a modest feature collection instead of the massive tileset.

Is there any example of code for showing features by given values?

Answer (score 10):

The ["Filter symbols by toggling a list" example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/) toggles the visibility of whole layers. For more fine grained filtering use map.setFilter, see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfilter.

`map.setFilter('my-layer', ['==', 'SortOFFruit', 'Apple']);`

Comment: Is there any difference using the map#setFilter vs the filter option in the layer definition? https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#filter

Comment: Apparently `setFilter` supports also an `options` object, with atm only a single option for validating the filter.